# Pass encrypted parameters with Deep Linking

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I am trying to open another app from my react-native application(kind of app launcher). I understand that deep linking must be implemented on the app that I am trying to open, but in addition to that, I want to pass parameters(probably encrypted) from my react-native application so that another app can use those parameters. The parameter that I want to pass is sensitive and hence I want to keep it encrypted. So far I am not able to find anything related to the same. Is there a way to achieve the same.